# How to declare correctly a route with facultative authentication in openApi 3.0 specification?

Tags: openapi, swagger-editor

I have a route that returns the content of a public article. If the user is logged, the route returns a different content (a content with additionnal details).
I don't know how to declare this in my openApi definition.
I couldn't find anything about this in the official doc.

My securitySchemes definition :

```yaml
components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
```

My route declaration :

```yaml
 /article/{slug}:
    get:
      tags:
        - articles
      summary: Return an article with more detail for authenticated users
      operationId: get_detail_article
      parameters:
        - name: slug
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      security: 
        - {}
        - bearerAuth: []
      responses:
        "200":
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Article"
```

Is the authentification part is correct ?

the result in swagger editor :

[image]

As you can see, the lock at right is black and closed, meaning that authentification is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which Swagger Editor version you are using but the security object is defined correctly for an `OR` condition, as in.. must use `bearerAuth` OR `none`

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: test
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: https://www.example.com
paths:
  "/article/{slug}":
    get:
      tags:
        - articles
      summary: Return an article with more detail for authenticated users
      operationId: get_detail_article
      parameters:
        - name: slug
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      security:
        - {}
        - bearerAuth: []
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Article"
components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
  schemas:
    Article:
      description: An Article
      type: string
```

I get a transparent lock on Swagger UI free account
[image: unlocked]

If I comment out the empty security, the lock changes to require only `bearerAuth`
[image: locked]

Comment: thank you for your answer, it helps me to understand the swagger editor.